# Sending a .mp4 file over sockets in python3

Tags: python-3.x, file, sockets, video, mp4

I am trying to make two small programs; one is a server which will receive mp4 files from a client. The client is just a small program that sends a .mp4 file located in its folder.

I am able to fully send the mp4 file and a file in the same size is created, but for some reason the mp4 gets corrupted or something else goes wrong and I am unable to play the mp4 file in QuickTime player or VLC.

I don't understand this as I am copying all bytes and sending then all in small packets. I would really appreciate some help or some tips.

#### Server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket, gethostname

s = socket()
host = gethostname()
port = 3399
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
n = 0

while True:
    print("Listening for connections...")
    connection, addr = s.accept()

    try:
        print("Starting to read bytes..")
        buffer = connection.recv(1024)

        with open('video_'+str(n), "wb") as video:
            n += 1
            i = 0
            while buffer:
                buffer = connection.recv(1024)
                video.write(buffer)
                print("buffer {0}".format(i))
                i += 1

        print("Done reading bytes..")
        connection.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
        break

s.close()
```

#### Client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket, gethostname, SHUT_WR

s = socket()
host = gethostname()
port = 3399

s.connect((host, port))

print("Sending video..")

with open("test.mp4", "rb") as video:
    buffer = video.read()
    print(buffer)
    s.sendall(buffer)

print("Done sending..")
s.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix  bugs in your server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket, gethostname

s = socket()
host = gethostname()
port = 3399
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
n = 0

while True:
    print("Listening for connections...")
    connection, addr = s.accept()

    try:
        print("Starting to read bytes..")
        buffer = connection.recv(1024)

        with open('video_'+str(n)+'.mp4', "wb") as video:
            n += 1
            i = 0
            while buffer:                
                video.write(buffer)
                print("buffer {0}".format(i))
                i += 1
                buffer = connection.recv(1024)

        print("Done reading bytes..")
        connection.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if connection:
            connection.close()
        break

s.close()
```

fix here:

```
with open('video_'+str(n)+'.mp4', "wb") as video:
```

and here:

```
while buffer:                
    video.write(buffer)
    print("buffer {0}".format(i))
    i += 1
    buffer = connection.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Ah yes that fixed it! Can't believe it was such a simple thing, thank you. Once you spend a good amount of time on your code you start reading past those things.